# :empty pseudoclass when adding dynamic content

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have read in this [sitepoint page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty#compatibilitysection) and [quirksmode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/empty.html) about the new `:empty` pseudoclass.

Sitepoint said that even when there is dynamic content appended, the empty style will still take effect. It is noted that firefox was the one who behaves this way.

Quirksmode said that it discards the empty state when it it filled in with some elements or text. the demo on this site works in my browser (chrome 19). So i assumed only firefox would be buggy.

However I have this piece of code in my plugin, which dynamically fills up a list with items, it doesn't seem to work, [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YprUV/5/) which appends list items, even if you click the button, the items won't appear until you try to debug it in the console (they magically appear when you click the `<li>` in the element tree).

Why is this happening, and is there a work around to "force-discard" the empty style?

I know there are other ways to do what I am doing in the fiddle (and currently doing one of these "other ways"), but the `:empty` method is a lot easier.

**UPDATE**:

added a remove item button. when the last item is removed, the list should disappear - still doesn't work. hmmm.. i'll try to check in another browser.

**FIX**

Temporary fix/alternative to using `:empty` and `display:none` is to have the element have zero `width`, `height`, `borders`, `margins`, and `paddings`. additionally, `position:absolute` to remove it from the flow.

Comment: I hadn't come across `:empty` until now, and +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: Well, they are appearing in FX10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fiddle you provided works for me with FF10 and IE9. It only fails in Chrome (18+)

Not sure why this happens, as the quirksmode page works in Chrome as well..

For the *force-discard* it seems to be do-able by setting almost any css property with code..

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/YprUV/9/

**Update**

Ok, i found this [***Chrome bug report***](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88906) that is about `:empty` selector  misbehaving when used with `display:none`

It is marked as fixed, but perhaps we should re-oopen it..

Here is a test that does not use `display:none` (*it just changes the background color*) and it works just fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/YprUV/11/

Comment: just tested in Opera 11.61 and IE9. seems like it's a problem with Chrome. I was considering explicitly adding `display:block` to make it work.