# :empty pseudo class issue with added/removed content and sibling combinators

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to set style for a `<div>` following an empty `<ul>`.

This is simple code i'm currently testing: (OS is win7)

### Basic jsFiddle DEMO

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btnAdd">add new LI</button>
<button class="btnRemove">remove last LI</button>
<ul></ul>
<div>Should be red if UL is empty</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul:empty + div {
    color:red;    
}
```

**jQuery:** (not relevant to issue, just for testing purpose)

```
$('.btnAdd').on('click', function () {
    $('ul').append('<li>LI</li>');
});

$('.btnRemove').on('click', function () {
    $('ul').find('li').last().remove();
});
```

**Expected behaviour:**

In all major browsers, when adding element to `<ul>`, style set for empty `<ul>` following `<div>` shouldn't be applied. When removing all `<li>`, style should be reapplied to targeted `<div>`.

**Current behaviour:**

- **Firefox** handles it with no problem, get expected result.
- **Chrome** removes red color for following DIV when UL is no more empty,
  but doesn't reapply it when UL is empty again (removing all LIs from
  UL)
- **IE10/11** just apply CSS `:empty` pseudo-class as by default, not reacting to any content added or removed

Googling it, i've find some workarounds but most seem outdated and none fix issue here, none i can't find at least.

For chrome, i've found that setting a CSS rule `:empty` for UL fixes it, but <strike>really i don't know what's going on</strike>: `ul:empty {}` (ya this is an empty CSS rule?!) ***<-- I guess now it forces an UI repaint on chrome*** ?!

### Fixed jsFiddle for chrome

Unfortunatley, this doesn't fix behaviour on IE10/11.

### So anyone knows a way to make it works on all major browsers???

**UPDATE 1:**

Seems like bug is related to next sibling selector `+`, even using `~` doesn't give consistent result on chrome. But if applying style directly to `:empty` element, all seems to work correctly on all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/EyEa7/ 
But my goal here is to target sibling element of `:empty` element, not the empty element directly.

**UPDATE 2:**

Forcing an UI redraw fixes it on all browsers, e.g using `$('body').hide().show(0);` once content has been updated: [See DEMO forcing redraw](http://jsfiddle.net/Je6UY/)

But, i'd really more appreciate a fix which doesn't involve any javascript code.

The question now could be:

- **How can i force IE10/11 to repaint UI using only CSS?** *(hoping this is a relevant question regarding this issue)*

Comment: Unfortunately IE is always lagging behind. Your best bet would be to use features like this to enhances the user experience for the browsers that support such niceties, But don't rely on them for functionality as there will always been someone browsing the site in IE7/8. Your chrome fix works for me on Chrome 34

Comment: @AshleyMedway I'm not looking to support any browsers which don't support natively `:empty` pseudo-class. I'm just looking to get it works as expected on relevant browsers. Anyway, thx for your input

Comment: @A.Wolff i tested it in ie its work first time but when we add li then its not working right is it same with you?

Comment: Just noted, if `~` used then after adding or removing a element, we need to click on the document/page to see the default behavior of `:empty` on Chrome, Win 8.

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit If i understand correctly you, ya, i have same behaviour on IE10/11

Comment: @Mr_Green Using `ul:empty ~ div`, TABLE needs to lose focus on first LI added to 'update' style. That's quite strange!  EDIT: didn't see your updated comment, same behaviour here on Win7

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tacuxori/1/edit 

Please check this url it will work wait for this 10 or more seconds.

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit Which part is the fix?! In IE, now it works in some way even looks like same bug as using `ul:empty ~ div` selector in chrome, UL needs to loose focus to update style, strange!  http://jsbin.com/tacuxori/2/edit

Comment: Ya actually @A.Wolff i don't know much information about this.But i googled it and find some tools so i tried it.

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit Indeed, looks like related to jsbin vs jsfiddle and maybe how is handled iframe or maybe auto run script mode on jsbin, don't know. http://jsbin.com/tacuxori/3/edit

Comment: This seems not to depend on iframe, jsFiddle or jsbin particularity : http://fiddle.jshell.net/Je6UY/3/show/light/

Comment: You can force a repaint with CSS3 `animate`. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome/22025804#22025804 maybe it's applicable for your situation

Comment: There is actually a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443500/empty-pseudoclass-when-adding-dynamic-content

Comment: @Brewal Thx for the link but i already tested it and doesn't apply here unfortunately, as i tested it :(

Comment: @pstenstrm Thx, i'm testing it. UPDATE: not works on IE :( Fixes it on chrome but even empty CSS rule fixes it on chrome

Comment: @Ashley Medway: "Unfortunately IE is always lagging behind." Likewise with Chrome. It's not just IE anymore, hasn't been for a while. Both browsers clearly need some way to force a repaint here even though repaints should be performed automatically based on changes to the DOM. And this isn't even the only problem that Chrome has with sibling combinators.

Comment: @pstenstrm It was the right way to force repaint. I had tried the linked solution but didn't work (of course i had removed prefix for animation). But indeed using animation was a working way, so thank to you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this will work, but it's not particularly pretty:

```
ul:empty {}

ul:empty + div {
    color: red;
}

ul + div {
    animation: repaint 1000s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes repaint {
    from { zoom: 1; }
    to { zoom: 0.99999; }
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/vd2Hx/

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and IE.

Comment: Wow, that's really nice! I mean what an awful fix that works, thank you   so much! :)

Comment: I will go with it until this bug will be fixed, again thank you!